# Android: using marquee with TalkBack (Accessibility)

Tags: android, accessibility, marquee, talkback

I'm developing an application adapted to people with `visual disabilities`. If the device has an `Android API` greater than 14 I want to enhance `Talkback` a bit.

I have a `ListView` filling the whole screen where each row has just one `TextView`. Since the text might be quite long, I wanted to use `marquee` and single line to scroll the text when the user clicks in it.

I tested it **without `Talkback`** and it works:

[image: Marquee works]

So I decided to test it **with Talkback active**. In this case, I have two kind of problems:

1- Some rows doesn't scroll at all.

2- Some rows scroll, but I can't see more text than the one that is shown when the text isn't scrolled:

[image: Marquee doesn't work]

I don't know why some rows scroll and some doesn't, I use the same code for all of them.

To change the background color and start the marquee I'm adding an `AccessibilityDelegate` to each row.

This is the layout for each row:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rowTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is some of my adapter's code:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView == null){ // If the View is not cached
        // Inflates the Common View from XML file
        convertView = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_simple_row, parent, false);
    }

    TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowTextView);
    tv.setText( list.get(position) );
    convertView.setContentDescription( list.get(position) );

    addAccessibilityDelegate(tv, position); // Add delegate to the TextView to detect touches

    tv.setSingleLine(true);

    if(position == selected){

        // The user touched this row: Change background color to green. 

        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        tv.setSelected(true);

    }
    else{

        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tv.setSelected(false);

    }

    return convertView;
}

protected void addAccessibilityDelegate( View v, final int position ){

    v.setAccessibilityDelegate(new AccessibilityDelegate(){
        @Override
        public void onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(View host, AccessibilityEvent event) {
            super.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(host, event);
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View host,
                AccessibilityNodeInfo info) {
            super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPopulateAccessibilityEvent(View host, AccessibilityEvent event) {
            super.onPopulateAccessibilityEvent(host, event);

            if(event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_HOVER_ENTER){
                focusBackground(position);
            }
        }
    });     
}

public void focusBackground(int position){

    if(selected != position){
        selected = position;
        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
    }
}
```

Anybody knows if I can use marquee with Talkback?

Thank you!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the AccessibilityDelegate, exactly? In general, your application shouldn't special-case hover events because that breaks the interaction model that's consistent elsewhere in Android.

Comment: The AccessibilityDelegate detects TYPE_VIEW_HOVER_ENTER events. I use them to change the background color of the touched View (for people with low vision) and to play a sound to let the user know how many views are left in the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=68333) on the Android bug tracker, it looks like Accessibility services interfere with the ellipsize property on TextViews. I was having similar issues with `android:ellipsize="start"` jumping to the start of the string until I disabled the LastPass Accessibility service. I verified that the Talkback service caused the same issue.